# Javascript error: function expected

Tags: javascript

I have this javascript and I get the error "function expected". I can't see anything wrong with my javascript. Please help. Thanks.

```
function checkrewardname()
{
var my=document.getElementById("Rname");
var con=my.value;
 var mine=document.getElementById("forref").value.split('\n');

if (con == "")
        {
            alert("Enter a Reward Name.");
    }
 else
    { 
    var i=0;
    while(i<=mine.length)
         {
            if (mine(i) == con)//error here
                {
                    alert("Duplicate reward. Please enter a new reward.");
                }
            else
                {
                    document.getElementById("validate").click();
                    alert("The reward has been saved.");
                }
            i++;
        }   
     }
}`
```

Answer (score 6):

`mine` is an array but you are calling it as if it were a function.  Use `mine[i]` rather than `mine(i)` and you'll access the array by index rather than generating an error.  (Just a note; most C-style languages use `[` and `]` for array access and reserve `(` and `)` for function invocation).

Answer (score 0):

You also have `while(i<=mine.length)`

shouldn't it be `while(i < mine.length)`